# Increase Limit of 3 Mentions per Post

Tags: 2013, my-site, social, limitations

Using SharePoint 2013 social features/mysite.

Just realized that there is a limit of 3 mentions (@ tags) per post in the microblog list for SharePoint 2013. Does anyone know of a way to increase that limit? I'm not finding a configuration for it anywhere (unlike the limits on number of people/docs/sites to follow) so I'm afraid it is a hard limit that would require overriding a dll (or more) to change. Can anyone confirm this or point me in the right direction if I'm wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that this is the behaviour. And I do not see a way to configure/override this at the moment. Therefore I would log a case with MS support to see if this can be made configurable.

Some blogs to confirm this:
http://www.jeremythake.com/2013/01/the-current-state-of-sharepoint-2013-social-collaboration/

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/3281fd82-cf74-409e-bd2b-7a6703efbab5/mention-more-than-3-people?forum=sharepointsearch

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/222906.aspx - This is for a newsfeed post. It allows only 6 mentions.